# Nodejs + Heroku: Using `cp` command in `postinstall`, but the files don't exists for the running server

Tags: node.js, heroku, materialize

I'm using `materializecss` and `express`.
To make the css/js files of materializecss available I copy them during `postinstall`.

The issue is, in the Heroku build logs I see the `postinstall` runs:

```
> ... postinstall
> cp -r ./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/ ./www/
```

The directory is made public via express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), 'www')))
```

In the `www` directory there is also the `index.html` located, which is available and works.
Also locally it works.
But trying to load the js/css files on the Heroku running app ends in 404 errors.

Maybe it makes some difference: The files are not in git, they are excluded via `.gitignore` file.

Did I miss something why it works locally, but not on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, I removed the `postinstall` and deliver the `materializecss` dist files directly out of `node_modules` via:

```
;[
  ['/css/materialize.css', 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'],
  ['/js/materialize.js', 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js'],
].forEach(([urlPath, filePath]) => {
  app.get(urlPath, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules', filePath))
  })
})
```

Also this approach makes it really easy to serve different files in different environments (e.g. `.min` files on production environments):

```
const staticFiles = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? [
      ['/css/materialize.css', 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'],
      ['/js/materialize.js', 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js']
    ]
  : [
      ['/css/materialize.css', 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'],
      ['/js/materialize.js', 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js']
    ]
staticFiles.forEach(([urlPath, filePath]) => {
  app.get(urlPath, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules', filePath))
  })
})
```